# Pointcloud to RGB raster (orthomosaic)

Tags: qgis, point-cloud, orthophoto

I am trying to create an orthomosaic for as cheap as possible. The project I am working on has absolutely no budget and the methods I use need to be easily used by someone who has no experience in GIS/coding/command line use. With QGIS having the functionality to display point clouds, is there any way to export or save the point cloud as an orthomosaic/TIFF/JPEG form? WebODM is possible but the person mentioned above is unable to use command lines.

Currently, I have taken to using cropped images of the pointcloud and georeferencing and merging the images to form a whole image, but this is time-consuming and ineffective.

Comment: I havent tried WebODM but isnt the purpose of it, not having to use the command line (like odm, which I have used)?

Comment: How big is your data?